# HTML5 Section 508 Compliance with a table of dynamically generated non-labeled inputs

Tags: html, section508

So for example if my table looks like this:

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <td>Field 1</td>
            <td>Field 2</td>
            <td>Field 3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

Just for example as a general lay out. However the amount of rows is being dynamically generated based on a series of conditions from angularJS (too much to post in here) **How do I add non-visible labels to the input fields in a way that it is 508 compliant?** I am not familiar with accessibility in this way. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Use the aria-labelledby attribute on the input elements to reference the header columns.

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th id="field1">Field 1</td>
        <th id="field2">Field 2</td>
        <th id="field3">Field 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" aria-labelledby="field1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" aria-labelledby="field2" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" aria-labelledby="field3" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="text" aria-labelledby="field1" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" aria-labelledby="field2" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text" aria-labelledby="field3" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```